# Solve linear system of equations with free variables MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scientific-computing

This is a `3*5` matrix and there are 2 free variables. I don't know if this is the best way to solve this in MATLAB. But it doesn't work and output `Empty sym: 0-by-1`

```
clear x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5
syms x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5

eqn1 = x_1+0*x_2+3*x_3+2*x_4-4*x_5==4 ;
eqn2 = 2*x_1+x_2+6*x_3+5*x_4+0*x_5==7 ;
eqn3 = -x_1+x_2-3*x_3-x_4+x_5==-5 ;

tic ;

res = solve([eqn1,eqn2,eqn3]) ;

toc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the symbolic math toolbox for a simple system of linear equations. You're better off using [`mldivide`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), which is common enough that it has the shorthand `\`.

For a system `Ax = b`, where `x` is a vector of x values, `A` is a matrix of coefficients, and `b` is their product (right hand side of your system), you can solve it by

```
x = A\b;
```

So

```
A = [1  0  3  2 -4; 
     2  1  6  5  0; 
    -1  1 -3 -1  1];

b = [4; 7; -5];

x = A\b
>> ans = [0; 0; 2; -1; 0];
```

You can manually check that this result (`x3=2, x4=-1, x1=x2=x5=0`) works.

Comment: I need the free variables to be represented. i.e. I need the solution space, not a particular solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a QR or LU decomposition

```
>> [l,u] = lu(A)

l =

          0.5     -0.33333            1
            1            0            0
         -0.5            1            0


u =

            2            1            6            5            0
            0          1.5            0          1.5            1
            0            0            0            0      -3.6667

>> c = l\b

c =

            7
         -1.5
            0
```

Then switch to `Uy = L\b = c` problem. Now you have,

```
[2            1            6            5            0][x1]   [ 7  ]
[0          1.5            0          1.5            1][x2] = [-1.5]
[0            0            0            0      -3.6667][x3]   [ 0  ]
                                                       [x4]
                                                       [x5]
```

Last one removes `x5` and hence row 3/column 5. And from the rest you can check the solution space.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `A` is an m-by-n matrix, and that `b` is a `n`-dimensional vector. You want to know all the solution to `A x = b` in the case of `m<n`, and it is expressed as following:

`x = x_0 + K y`, .. (1)

where `x_0` is an arbitrary solution to the original equation, `A x = b`, `K` is a `n`-by-`(n-m)` matrix whose columns constitute a basis of the null space (also called kernel) of `A`, and `y` is an arbitrary `(n-m)`-dimensional vector. This `y` corresponds to what you call "free parameter".

Let me explain about the matrix `K` more. The null space of the matrix `A` is a set of vectors `v` such that `A v = 0`. This set of `v` is actually a vector space of `(n-m)`-dimension, and any `v` can be expressed as a linear combination of `(n-m)` vectors, `k_1`, .., `k_{n-m}`, which are linearly independent with each other and satisfy `A k_i = 0` (`i=1,..,n-m`). The choice of `k_1,..,k_{n-m}` is not unique.

You can substitute eq. (1) to `A x =b` to verify that it's indeed the solution because `A K = 0`. The term `K y` expresses all vectors `v` such that `A v=0`.

One method to find the matrix `K` is the singular value decomposition,

`A V = U S`,

where `V` and `U` are `n`-by-`n` and `m`-by-`m` orthogonal matrices, respectively, and `S` is a `m`-by-`n` diagonal matrix like,

```
S = [s_1   0    0    0    0 ]
    [ 0   s_2   0    0    0 ]
    [ 0    0   s_3   0    0 ]
```

Since the last `(n-m)` columns of `S` are zero vectors, the last `(n-m)` columns of the product `U S` are also zero vectors. This means that the last `(n-m)` columns of `V` will yield zero vectors if we multiply `A` on them from the left. Therefore, these columns of `V` belongs to the null space of `A`. As they are linearly independent (as `V` is an orthogonal matrix), they constitute the basis of the null space. Therefore, we can set `K` as the last `(n-m)` columns of `V` found in the singular value decomposition.

I don't know how to do the singular value decomposition in Matlab, but there must be a function for it.